# How to convert font size in percentages?

Tags: html, css

How to convert font size in percentages for adaptive design? Now `span` element has property: `font-size: 14px;`.

Can I convert this to %, that when I scale page it will be changed proportionally?
Or is it bad practic?

Comment: I recommend a combination of the answers given. Set the root element's font-size using vh or vw units, then you can set other elements relative to that using em and rem units.

Comment: You can use `em` or `rem` instead of `px`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try `vh` *viewport height* and `vw` *viewport width*

```
<span class="s1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
<span class="s2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
```

CSS:

```
span.s1 {
   font-size: 5vh
}
span.s2 {
   font-size: 5vw
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h9e6ubdz/ Resize your window to see it in action. There is also a very helpfull list of all CSS units, wich you can find [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly what `em` and `rem` doing.

https://j.eremy.net/confused-about-rem-and-em/

> While em is relative to the font-size of its direct or nearest parent,
>   rem is only relative to the html (root) font-size.

Comment: And what I need use rem or em? How to define?

Comment: in short, if you define for example, `font-size: 18px` on `<html>` tag, you can then use for example `font-size: 0.9em` to simulate 90% of global font size.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work in first place. Using % always inherits from a parent. So let's assume you've set a `font-size` of `14px` in your body.

```
body {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Using `font-size: 100%;` would just use 100% of 14px. So basically 50% would be the same as 7px, no matter how small/big your window is.

I would suggest using `em` or even `rem`. Both are relative values. While `em` is relative to it's parent container, `rem` is relative to the root container which in most cases reflects the `<body>`. Besides of that `em` and `rem` could be read as 'multiply font x times'. According to our previous example with 14px, using 2em would result in a font-size with 28px and so on.

The following example should clarify things a bit.

```
.multiply-by-one {
  font-size: 1rem; /* font-size: 14px; */
}

.multiply-by-two {
  font-size: 2rem; /* font-size: 28px; */
}
```

Comment: What does it mean: `always inherits from a parent.` inherits from parent font-size?

Comment: Yes. From the parent containers font-size. E.g. a div inside your body inherits from the body.

Comment: `result in a font-size with 28px and so on` how 28px if I have 14px, ot I can have two font-size?

Comment: It requires that body must have ` font-size: 14px;`?

Comment: Your body will always have a font-size. If you do not specify any size your browser will just set its default one which mostly is around 14px.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways for scaling font sizes. The common ways are rem, em.

Here you can read more about it

> https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/comprehensive-guide-when-to-use-em-vs-rem--cms-23984

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **em** and not **px** 
**em** it's done precisely for that.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using percentages use `em`, `rem`, `vh` or `vw`

[Viewport Sized Typography using vh and vw](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

[Understanding and Using rem Units in CSS](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/)

If you decide to use vh and vw don't forget to use a fallback for retro compatibility with older browser